# jquery fileDownload plugin - show error 'offsetParent is not set -- cannot scroll'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jquery fileDownload but it's showing 'offsetParent is not set -- cannot scroll' error in firebug.

Here is my code. It's simple.

```
$.fileDownload("/TmpFiles/Test.pdf")
                            .done(function () { alert('File download a success!'); })
                            .fail(function () { alert('File download failed!'); });
```

Can anyone help me to fix the issue?

Comment: That error must be coming from other script check the line number of errror and find post the respective code too. this seems to be correct.

Comment: Jai, the problem is it doesn't even show which line/which file. In firebug it juz show that 'offsetParent is not set -- cannot scroll'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue. The inline PDF viewer causing this error, so what I did is to force the apache to download the PDF file. So far I figured out this solution with .htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(pdf)$">
    <ifModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Content-disposition "attachment"
    </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

In your example, you need to place the .htaccess file in the /TmpFiles/ directory to apply the rule to the *.pdf files.